# bufferedReader - reading out lines in sections from a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a text file which has a format similar to this:

===Header1====

LINE1

LINE2

LINE3

===Header2====

LINE1

LINE2

LINE3

What I'm trying to do is parse these out individually to a String variable, so when the reader detects `"====Header1===="`, it will also read all lines underneath til it detects `"===Header2==="`, which will be variable Header1 and so on

Im having issues at the moment with reading out the lines till it detects the next header. I was wondering could anyone shed some light on this? Here is what i have so far

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE))) {
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("============= Header 1 ===================")) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
        if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("============= Header 2 ===================")) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
        if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("============= Header 3 ===================")) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of the headers. You seem to want to print out all the lines anyway, so there's no need to care whether the line is a header or not.

Comment: @Kayaman sorry, i forgot to mention im trying to split each header and its lines into individual string variables

Comment: If you want to read the lines between the headers, you have to call `readLine()` some more. Hard to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `readLines()` method which will read the lines till the next header and loads the lines to an arraylist, call `readLines()` from `main()` as shown in the below code with inline comments:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     BufferedReader br = null;
      try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(FILE)));

           //read the 2rd part of the file till Header2 line
           List<String> lines1 = readLines(br, 
                              "============= Header 2 ===================");

           //read the 2rd part of the file till Header3 line
           List<String> lines2 = readLines(br, 
                              "============= Header 3 ===================");

            //read the 3rd part of the file till end        
            List<String> lines3 = readLines(br, "");

        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //close BufferedReader
        }
   }

   private static List<String> readLines(BufferedReader br, String nextHeader) 
                                                  throws IOException {
                 String sCurrentLine;
                 List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                 while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     if("".equals(nextHeader) || 
                         (nextHeader != null &&      
                       nextHeader.equals(sCurrentLine))) {
                         lines.add(sCurrentLine);
                     }
                 }
                 return lines;
      }
```